# GroupBy two level nested list using Lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have 3 classes :

```
public class ThirdClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? PoolId { get; set; }
}

public class SecondClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ThirdClass> ThirdClassList { get; set; }
}

public class FirstClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<SecondClass> SecondClassList { get; set; }
}

   // create a nested list
    FirstClass first = new FirstClass("First");
    SecondClass second1 = new SecondClass("Second1");
 
    second1.ThirdClassList.Add(new ThirdClass("Inground", null));
    second1.ThirdClassList.Add(new ThirdClass("Above", 1));
    second1.ThirdClassList.Add(new ThirdClass("SPA", 2));
    first.SecondClassList.Add(second1);

    SecondClass second2 = new SecondClass("Second2");
 
    second2.ThirdClassList.Add(new ThirdClass("Inground", null));
    second2.ThirdClassList.Add(new ThirdClass("SPA", 2));
    first.SecondClassList.Add(second2);
    
    SecondClass second3 = new SecondClass("Second3");
    
    second3.ThirdClassList.Add(new ThirdClass("Inground", null));
    second3.ThirdClassList.Add(new ThirdClass("Above", 1));
    second3.ThirdClassList.Add(new ThirdClass("SPA", 2));
    first.SecondClassList.Add(second3);
    
    SecondClass second4 = new SecondClass("Second4");
    
    second4.ThirdClassList.Add(new ThirdClass("Inground", null));
    second4.ThirdClassList.Add(new ThirdClass("SPA", 3));
  
    first.SecondClassList.Add(second4);
```

How can I group by the last PoolId (if the SecondClass has multiple ThirdClasses) or the PoolId of their only ThirdClass, and Then Group by the ThirdClass Name the multiple SecondClass that have the same ThirdClass Name.

Using Lambda expression I'm trying to get the result to look like:

```
[
  {
    "VoteID": 2,
    "PoolTypes": [
      {
        "Name": "Inground", 
        "Ingredients": [
          {
            "Name": "Second1"
          },
          {
            "Name": "Second2"
          },
          {
            "Name": "Second3"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Name": "Above", 
        "Ingredients": [
          {
            "Name": "Second1"
          },
          {
            "Name": "Second3"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Name": "SPA", 
        "Ingredients": [
          {
            "Name": "Second1"
          },
          {
            "Name": "Second2"
          },
          {
            "Name": "Second3"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "VoteID": 3,
    "PoolTypes": [
      {
        "Name": "Inground", 
        "Ingredients": [
          {
            "Name": "second4"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Name": "SPA", 
        "Ingredients": [
          {
            "Name": "second4"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: What does "SecondClass that have the same ThirdClass Name" mean when a particular `SecondClass` can have multiple `ThirdClass` Names? Use the last `ThirdClass` Name?

Answer (score 0):

How you can group by two level nested list is like

```
var myResult = first.SecondClassList
    .SelectMany(s => s.ThirdClassList
        .Select(t => new { PoolId = t.PoolId ?? s.ThirdClassList.SingleOrDefault(x => x.PoolId.HasValue)?.PoolId, Name = t.Name, SecondClassName = s.Name }))
    .Where(x => x.PoolId.HasValue)
    .GroupBy(x => x.PoolId)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        VoteID = g.Key,
        PoolTypes = g.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
            .Select(g2 => new
            {
                Name = g2.Key,
                Ingredients = g2.Select(x => new { Name = x.SecondClassName })
            })
    });
```